# While loop freezes game - Is there anything else which can rotate an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash, transform, freeze

I am trying to create a rotating light source for a TBS game, which will rotate at the end of the turn. For this purpose I have used events; I have two scripts, one which advances the turn:

```
public delegate void Time(int t);
public static event Time Time_Change;
public int t = 1;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        t = t + 1;
        if (t > 8) { t = 1; }
        Debug.Log(t);
        if (Time_Change != null)
        {
            Time_Change(t);
        }
    }
```

(There are eight day/night Phases) and one that receives the signal and moves the light it is attached to:

```
public int angle = 85;

void Start () {
    Time_Controller.Time_Change += Move_Lights;
}


void Move_Lights(int t)
{

//phase detection, set angle variable

if (t % 2 == 0)
    {    
        //----------------------------------------       
        while (transform.eulerAngles.x != angle)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        //----------------------------------------
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the game and press enter, Everything freezes and the only way to close Unity is through task manager (which also shows a spike in Unity's CPU usage while the game is frozen). I have, by process of elimination, (everything works fine without it) tracked the faulty line down to be

```
while (transform.eulerAngles.x != angle)
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```

as marked out above. What do I do? I've tried various ways of rotating the light source, but anything is yet to even prevent a crash.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game freezes because it's caught in an infinite loop with your inequality. The while loop only exits when the float value of your transform is equal to your `angle`, which will virtually never be true because of the precision of a float. When using equalities with floats you should be putting a tolerance on your comparison. If you are looking for an exact angle, this of course will not be the approach you want to use.

```
// while the transforms angle is not within .5f of the desired...
while (Mathf.abs(transform.eulerAngles.x-angle) > .5f)
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it working, with a combination of both answers.

Comment: Problem - When Angle is set to a value between 90 and 270, the program goes right past the rotation needed. What do i do?!? I've looked everyehere and no-one has an awnser!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a coroutine here.

```
void Move_Lights(int t)
{
    //phase detection, set angle variable

    if (t % 2 == 0)
    {    
        StartCoroutine(RotateLight());
    }
}

IEnumerable RotateLight()
{
    while (transform.eulerAngles.x != angle)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        yield return null;
    }
    yield break;
}
```